# Understanding and implementing the last step in the 3-Step Latent Class Analysis using covariates from Vermunt 2010

Tags: r, probability, multinomial-logit, latent-class, model-based-clustering

I am interested in implementing the 3-Step approach for LCA with covariates ($Z_i$) in R.  According to [Vermunt (2010)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.819.5384&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the "Standard" three-step approach would involve (mentioned in pages 5 and 6):

1. Step 1: Fit an LCA model without covariates, and
2. Step 2: Compute $P(W=s|X=t)$ or the "weights" for each observation ($Y_i$) by the posterior probabilities $P(X=t|Y_i)$
3. Step 3: Fit a "weighted" multinomial logistic regression model.

**Question 1:** It is not clear how to fit the multinomial logistic model in R when there is proportional assignment (i.e. $w_{it}\ne0 \forall t\in[1,2,..T]$, where $T$ is the number of latent classes).

**Question 2:** In pages 8 and 9 of [1](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.819.5384&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Vermunt also states that the method proposed by [Bolck, Croon, and Hagenaars (2004)](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/cuppolals/v_3a12_3ay_3a2004_3ai_3a01_3ap_3a3-27_5f00.htm) improves the results by establishing the relationship between $P(W=s|Z_i)$ and $P(X=t|Z_i)$ and this is followed by the expression $E=AD$ from which $P(X=t|Z_i)$ can be estimated.  Given that there is a way to perform the "weighted" multinomial logistic regression, it is possible to handle negative weights which appear in the matrix $A$ (mentioned in page 9)? If possible, I want to know if the [SAS Macro for 3-Step Analysis](https://www.methodology.psu.edu/files/2020/04/LCA_Covariates_3Step_UG_1.0.pdf) is based on the method by [2](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/cuppolals/v_3a12_3ay_3a2004_3ai_3a01_3ap_3a3-27_5f00.htm) from their description of the 3rd step on page 5.

Thank you